# Isn't the (insert platform-specific site here) redundant?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been posting my Android questions to Stack Overflow and only recently discovered android.stackexchange.com (which says something about its visibility as I've been posting and answering Android questions for a year).

I'm really happy there is an Android-specific site but it seems redundant to have a dedicated Android site and a plethora of Android tags on Stack Overflow. Even worse, more people post Android questions on Stack Overflow than Android Stack Exchange. Worse still, the only way to maximize a question's visibility is to post on both. Ugh.

As I said I like the Android-specific site, I think there should be only one or the other. Or better integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That site is for Android users. Android developers should still ask questions on Stack Overflow. From [the Android.SE FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Android Enthusiasts - Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system.

Comment: I see. Thank you! May I suggest that text be added in a more visible location since I see many development questions there.

Comment: ...and we close them as quick as we find them. That we don't accept development questions is right there in the FAQ. How more visible do you want it?

Comment: @BarryFruitman Plenty (most?) of our visitors aren't programmers.  Putting it in their face is just annoying.  We do expect everyone to know what they're doing when they post though, hence the FAQ :).  If you have any tips on how to get people to read the FAQ I'm sure we're all ears.

Comment: @Matthew Read: Redirecting new users to the FAQ after registration will force them to at least glance at it. Once there, it's hard to ignore that first, most-important question. I don't know anyone who reads the FAQ before they have a question. We can either accept that fact or waste our time deleting posts.

Comment: @ale More visible than in the FAQ.